# How to send legible faxes?

Tags: windows-7, scanner, dpi, fax

When sending faxes, the receiver always says that the fax is illegible...
What the best dpi, contrast, brightness, etc (when scanning) in order to send a legible fax?

PS: I'm using Win7's built-in fax software. I don't know anyone that owns a color fax machine to receive faxes, then I need to send black/white or grayscale option. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, you're scanning something into Windows and then faxing it out from there.

Remember that fax technology only supports 1-bit color depth.  There is no greyscale.  So set your scanner to do that and then tweak the preview until you can read it.

Answer (score 1):

I always set my fax machine to "superfine" resolution, which seems to help a lot, assuming the other end supports it.

These are the supported resolutions, according to Wikipedia:

- Horizontal: 100 scan lines per inch

  - Vertical: 100 scan lines per inch
- Horizontal: 200 or 204 scan lines per inch

  - Vertical: 100 or 98 scan lines per inch ('Standard')
  - Vertical: 200 or 196 scan lines per inch ('Fine')
  - Vertical: 400 or 391 (note not 392) scan lines per inch ('Superfine')
- Horizontal: 300 scan lines per inch

  - Vertical: 300 scan lines per inch
- Horizontal: 400 or 408 scan lines per inch

  - Vertical: 400 or 391 scan lines per inch ('Ultrafine')